# extract line that begin with a given pattern in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I have a multi-line text and I just want to extract the whole line that begin with a given pattern. For exemple, I have this bloc of text

```
v=0
o=Z 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=Z
c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1
t=0 0
m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 3 110 8 0 98 101
a=rtpmap:110 speex/8000
a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000
a=fmtp:98 mode=20
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-15
a=sendrecv
```

And I want to extract the line : c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1 by using the pattern prefix c=IN

It is possible ?

Comment: Everything is possible. You just have to code it. What did you code?

Comment: Try something. If it works, great. If it does not work, post the code and we'll try to help.

Comment: stupid guys pff. go to sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with pattern `c=IN.*`, where `.*` is all the characters till the end of the line, and the `Matcher` like:

```
String ttt = "v=0\n" +
                "o=Z 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
                "s=Z\n" +
                "c=IN IP4 127.0.0.1\n" +
                "t=0 0\n" +
                "m=audio 8000 RTP/AVP 3 110 8 0 98 101\n" +
                "a=rtpmap:110 speex/8000\n" +
                "a=rtpmap:98 iLBC/8000\n" +
                "a=fmtp:98 mode=20\n" +
                "a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000\n" +
                "a=fmtp:101 0-15\n" +
                "a=sendrecv";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("c=IN.*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ttt);
if (matcher.find())
     System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Or you can split it by `\n` into an array of the lines and iterate over this array, until you get the one, which starts with `c=IN`.